# SLDS Assets global variable not working from Visualforce?

Tags: visualforce, slds, urlfor, asset

I'm blowing through some Trailheads and this bit is not working:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" docType="html-5.0">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Salesforce Lightning Design System Trailhead Module</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <!-- Import the Design System style sheet -->
    <apex:slds />
</head>
<body>
<div class="slds-scope">
...
<span class="slds-avatar slds-avatar_medium">
  <img src="{!URLFOR($Asset.SLDS, '/images/avatar1.jpg')}" alt="" />
</span>
```

According to [the docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_styling_slds.htm) it should be plug-n-play.

Interestingly, a static url `/apexpages/slds/latest/assets/images/avatar1.jpg` (mentioned elsewhere by @sfdcfox) works just fine.

Any idea what's up in this dev org I'm using?

Comment: Hi Sean, and welcome to SFSE! I've gone ahead and put out a message on social media to see if we can get a response to this. I'm observing that the images are not working via $Asset, but the SVG icons are working.